# How to affect column label positions on a polar chart when grouping is enabled?

Tags: charts, highcharts, polar-coordinates

I tried suggestions from the Chat about how to affect the column labels on a polar chart (`distance`, `align`, `x` and `y`) but nothing seems to work, they never move, they aren't centered, they aren't conveniently positioned, and some overlap:

[image: Highcharts columns polar chart labels]

```
        plotOptions :
    {
        series :
        {
            pointPadding : 0.01,
            animation: false,
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: true,
            },
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              format: '<span>{point.name}</span>',
              style: {
                textShadow: false,
                width: 20,
                fontSize: "14px"
              },
            }
        },
        column:
        {
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              distance: -30,
              align: 'center',
              style: {
                textOutline: 'none'
              }
            }
          }
    },
```

Edit:

If I add `grouping : false,` to column plotOptions I get columns that are centered within their categories, and they overlap. Their labels then make more sense, since they're also centered down the category "pie slice":

[image: Highcharts column polar chart grouped]

```
plotOptions :
    {
      column :
      {
        grouping : false,
        dataLabels : {
          enabled : true,
          distance : 0,
          align : 'center',
          style : {
            textOutline : 'none',
            fontWeight : 'bold'
          }
        }
      },
  …
```

If I change chart type so it's regular column and not polar, the column labels are centered over their columns:

[image: column highcharts with labels]

So the problem happens only when columns are displayed on a polar chart and they are grouped.

How can I control the position of column labels when columns (xAxis) are grouped so they don't overlap?

Comment: here is no such option `column.dataLabels.distance`, however, `align`, `x`, and `y` should work correctly - check the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vr0zew35/. If the demo doesn't help you, please provide the full config of your chart or reproduce the issue in the online editor.

Comment: Thank you! The column labels that I want positioned over their columns seem to be positioned down the middle of each "pie slice", centered in each category area. I'm trying to cut it down to a simple example but that seems to be the issue, the way xAxis data is grouped isn't similar to any simple example I've seen.